# php count total string in files in directory and subdirectories

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, count, preg-match

i have multiple files in directory and subdirectories.
files standard as folowing

users.text examples

```
F: khkgjg1 3hs6q7a5x { expire=2016-08-21 13; afexpire=2017-08-20; email=kgtugh@kkk.com; Country=United State; country_code=US; hosted=none }
F: khkgjg2 hjfg545gh { expire=2016-09-21 13; afexpire=2017-08-20; email=kgtugh@kkk.com; Country=United State; country_code=US; hosted=none }
F: khkgjg3 hgdghgfh5 { expire=2017-08-21 13; afexpire=2017-08-20; email=kgtugh@kkk.com; Country=Duchland; country_code=DE; hosted=none }
F: khkgjg4 y5dhgfdh5 { expire=2015-08-21 13; afexpire=2017-08-20; email=kgtugh@kkk.com; Country=United State; country_code=US; hosted=none }
```

i have below code, i want it to count total lines that have this string
"country_code= US" in all txt or cfg files.

```
<?php
$path_to_check  = '/path/phpm/linessysf/test/';
$types_to_check = "{*,ap/*}.{txt,cfg}";
$countrycd = "US";

foreach (glob($path_to_check . $types_to_check, GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    foreach ($rows = file($filename) as $key => $row) {

        if (preg_match("#^F:.*?country_code=($countrycd);#is", $row, $valuesf)) {

        }
    }
}
echo $count_country;
```

I tried to do that but i fall, can anyone help,please?

Comment: `$count_country` isn't defined and is never incremented. Your pattern contains too much `.*?`, that can be problematic when the string doesn't match (too many possibilities to test before failing). Instead of building an array of lines with `file()`, you should read your file line by line with `fgets`. To filter lines and extract interesting data if needed, use simple string functions, like `strpos`, `explode`.

Comment: $count_country mean echo count total lines that have this string "country_code= US"

Comment: I know but where is it defined and where is it incremented?

Comment: i don't know how to do that , can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the counter increment after the preg_match:

```
if (preg_match("#\bcountry_code=$countrycd\b;#is", $row)) {
    $count_country++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. you are right. i don't know how to forget that